# Xamarin.Forms Free Nearby Places API

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project that needs to detect location. But this location information is not that reliable because It's just giving the latitude and longitude information. I want to get a list of places nearby the location taken from the user's phone.
I've researched Geocoding, Geocoder and Google Places for it. Google Places is not a free solution. They're trying to earn money. Geocoding and Geocoder aren't giving the nearby places. It's partially giving the whole address by PlaceMark data object.
Please anyone can help with it? Is there a NuGet package that I can use for free?
Thank you,
Have a good day!

Comment: Perhaps openstreetmaps has something you can use. But such services are often paid, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, actually I know that project It's been a while since the first I saw it but It's a basically map. Cafe, restaurant, pub, bar pins are not there. For example, you went to a shopping mall and want to do a check-in to your company. In that center, there are lots of shops so you have to select one of them so that's why I am trying to get the list of the nearby places.
Thank you for your answer,

Comment: There 1.2 billion+ items in OpenStreetMaps

Answer (score 1):

No one provide nearby places service free of cost. You have to select different provider for this service. Google is one of them and always best choice. For development purpose you can use google places service free of cost.

following are some famous provider for the near by places service

1. Google Places API
2. Map My India
3. Here Map

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer,
For Google Places API do you have any sample code?

Comment: You can check their documentation for the code. First you have to create project on their developer account then get API KEY to send request to their server.